# Android Google Chrome: CSS3 Responsive Layout Bug

Tags: android, google-chrome, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a problem when viewing this site with the latest Chrome for Android on my Stock Jelly Bean Gnex:
http://kwitter.org/walialu/1340969834

It renders as it should be when loading the page.
Then I flip my phone to change to landscape mode and it breaks the design. I need to refresh the page to let chrome re-rendering the page and then everything looks fine.

When viewing it on the stock Jelly Bean browser everything is rendering as expected.

The HTML for this site looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kwitter.org - Like Twitter with, but with more K!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_twitext/templates/default/template.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/gaia.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topbar"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="twitexts"><div class="twitext"><a href="/keanan"><div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('/_twitext/avatars/keanan.png');"></div></a>    <div class="userdata"><a href="/keanan"><div class="name">Keanan Williams</div><div class="username">+keanan<span>@kwitter.org</span></div></a><div class="posted_via">via Android Mobile Web</div><div class="date"><a href="/keanan/1340969834">2012-06-29 13:37:14</a></div></div><div class="text">I can&#039;t wait to get butter on my Galaxy Nexus. It is so fucking awesome, but watch for yourself!

</div></div></div>
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS for this site looks like this:

```
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #bbb;
        color: #999;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: #C0DEED url("/_twitext/templates/default/bg.png") repeat-x fixed;
    }

    a {
        color: #F92659;
    }

    kbd {
        background-color:#f7f7f7;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius:3px;
        box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
        color:#333;
        display:inline-block;
        font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:1.4;
        margin:0 .1em;
        padding:.1em .6em;
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    }

    .date a {
        color: #666;
    }


    button {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #CCC;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        background-color: #333;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }

    button:active {
        color: #FFF;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
        background-color: #555;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid #555;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
    }

    input,textarea {
        border: 1px solid #559;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #eef;
        color: #000;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    #post_window textarea, #edit_window textarea {
        width: 546px;
        max-width: 85%;
        height: 200px;
        max-height: 94%;
    }

    #post_window input {
        width: 546px;
        max-width: 85%;
    }

    .box-header {
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-top: -1px;
        padding: 5px;
        color: #000;
    }

    div.overlay {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    div.overlay.modal {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        text-align:center;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-image:url("/_twitext/images/overlay-bg.png");
    }

    div.overlay div {
        position: absolute;
        min-width:90px;
        min-height:90px;
        max-width: 96%;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
    }

    div.overlay div .window-destroy-button {
        float: right;
        margin-top: -5px;
        background-color: #900;
        color: #fff;
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
    }

    div.overlay div span {
        margin: -1px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        background-color: #3287D0;
        padding:10px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    div.overlay div div {
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px;
        max-width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        text-align:center;
        border: 0 none;
    }

    #topbar {
        background-color: #222;
        height: 42px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #topbar div {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 3px;
        width: 576px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        width: 96%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #twitexts {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext {

    }

    #twitexts .twitext .avatar {
        display: none;
        width: 96px;
        height: 96px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext .userdata {
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 86px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border-bottom: 0 none;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext .userdata a, #twitexts .twitext .userdata a:visited{
        color: #000;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext .userdata .name, #twitexts .twitext .userdata .username {
        float: left;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext .userdata .username {
        clear: both;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext .userdata .posted_via {
        padding-top: 10px;
        clear: both;
        color: #999;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext .userdata .date {
        clear: both;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext .userdata .username span {
        font-size: small;
        color: #666;
    }

    #twitexts .twitext .text  {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        color: #272822;
    }

    @media (min-width: 480px) {
        #twitexts .twitext .avatar {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-bottom: -30px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .userdata {
            margin-left: 120px;
            padding: 10px;
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .userdata .username {
            margin-top: -30px;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .text  {
            clear: both;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 640px) {
        #content {
            max-width: 576px;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .avatar {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        #twitexts {
            float: right;
            width: 576px;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .text  {
            float: left;
            width: 538px;
        }
        #postbar {
            float: left;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .userdata {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 0;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 430px;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .userdata .username {
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .userdata .posted_via {
            clear: both;
            margin-top: -40px;
            float: right;
            color: #999;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        #twitexts .twitext .userdata .date {
            float: right;
            margin-top: -20px;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-align: right;
        }
    }
```

Do you think this is a chrome for android specific rendering bug (because desktop chrome doesn't have this weird behaviour when resizing), or do you think I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The stock browser doesn't have this weird behaviour, neither Dolphin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is a Chrome for Android specific rendering bug, because the Dolphin (HD) and the stock browser are not showing this weird behaviour (plus, after a full page reload everything is showing up as expected).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before but couldn't find a fix. But it was bugged in landscape mode no matter what i did so i just locked it in portrait mode... But this page might have a few answers regarding bugs in chrome:

http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromecompatfaq

Best of luck anyway :)

Edit:
There's also someone discussing a similar problem here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?676871-google-chrome-layout-issue

Comment: Thx for your response, but I don't think that this is the same problem I am facing. I have no problem when in landscape mode - I only have one single problem when switching from portrait mode to landscape mode in Chrome for Android. When you reload the page (or are in landscape mode on the initial load) everything is fine. It seems that Chrome for Android has some sort of problem rearranging the elements..